# Which module is work good with profile2 to show profile complete status?

Tags: 7, users

I am using profile2 module in drupal 7. I want to use percentage to show profile complete status. I already use profile complete percentage module but i am not getting proper result. Please help which module is work with profile2. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [Profile Complete](https://www.drupal.org/project/pcp) module for Profile completion in Percentage.. I didn't use it. But I think it will help to u...

Comment: i already uses this... but i am not getting proper result...

Comment: this module is not integrate with profile2 fields...

Comment: if i want to show message forcefully i.e. "please complete atleast 60%"... then how can i do...

Comment: Use Rules module for this issue.

Comment: may you pls help me how to implement...

Comment: U have to customize the pcp-template.tpl.php file.

Comment: if($current_percent ≥60): print "please complete atleast 60%";endif;

Comment: click on create new rule.. but there is no option in "React on event" for profile completion... or something related to this

Comment: may u pls clarify your point...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16506/discussion-between-niks88-and-mahesh).

Comment: Profile % module is working gud.. but problem i face that... when i open the link i.e. "www.example.com/user" then it shows 36% & if i open the link i.e. "www.example.com" then it shows 32%... how to resolve this error... @Nandhana

Answer (score 0):

The Field_Complete module might also be of help:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2049963

Based on this blog post by the author, it should be compatible with Profile2:
http://drupal7ish.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/field-complete-and-profile2.html